# pcl::ConvexHull not instantiated for pcl::PointXY?

Tags: ros, pcl, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get a linker error:

undefined reference to  pcl::ConvexHullpcl::PointXY::reconstruct(pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXY&)

My manifest.xml includes "pcl" and "pcl_ros" listed as dependencies
Should I use some other point type for computing convex hull of 2D points?

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXY> rectConvexHull;  // the convex hull in ROS.

void compute2DConvexHull()
{
    if(rectConvexHull.size()>0)
        return;
    
    pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXY> computeConvexHull;
    
    computeConvexHull.setInputCloud(scene2DPtr);

    computeConvexHull.setIndices(getPointIndicesBoostPtr());

    computeConvexHull.reconstruct(rectConvexHull);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11632/pcl::convexhull-not-instantiated-for-pcl::pointxy?/) by [aa755](https://answers.ros.org/users/303/aa755/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-29**:
I'd suggest asking this on pcl-users; you'll probably get a quicker response there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not completely sure because it has been a while, but I believe you have to use `pcl::PointXYZ` with `z=0` (or another arbitrary constant) for all points. You can try to `#include <pcl/surface/impl/convex_hull.hpp>` instead, but if I remember correctly, the implementation actually expects 3D points and will choke on `pcl::PointXY`.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1